# Bootstrap rows inconsistent padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid template with 3 columns, and my first row in the column is being pushed by a few pixels. What CSS option do I need to change for this? I'm using bootstrap[image]

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <input type="redacted" class="form-control" id="redacted" placeholder="" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <input type="redacted" class="form-control" id="redacted" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <input type="redacted" class="form-control" id="redacted" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.gridMatchInputs {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] in your question?  The code provided does not illustrate the issue.  At first glance, I do not see multiple rows in your code so it seems like more code is missing

Comment: Please provide more information. Read the above link ^

Comment: Sorry, please see here

https://jsfiddle.net/cr798jmn/

Notice how the 2nd row is indented? I believe it's an issue because the 2nd row starts with a `select` but I'm not sure where to look to change this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `select` - check answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove this line `grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;` from your CSS and use `.row` when you want to have elements in a new row, I think you achieve what you are looking for

**See demo below**

```css
.gridMatchInputs {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="gridMatchInputs">
  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- column 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1" placeholder="1" required>
    </div>

    <!-- column 2 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2" placeholder="2">
    </div>
    <!-- column 3 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="3" placeholder="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- row 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <select class="form-control" id="select1">
        <option selected>select1</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <select class="form-control" id="select2">
        <option selected>select2</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <select class="form-control" id="select3">
        <option selected>select3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this was indeed it, I also had two column <divs> in the code as well which causes the indentation, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)